# wpf user control xaml null error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hello i have a wpf user control and when i add this code to the UserControl.Resources the designer is throwing a NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
<UserControl...
   <UserControl.Resources>

       <local:TaskDayTemplateSelector x:Key="TaskDayTemplateSelector">
        <local:TaskDayTemplateSelector.DefaultTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Opacity="0.6" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:TaskDayTemplateSelector.DefaultTemplate>
        <local:TaskDayTemplateSelector.TaskTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:TaskDayTemplateSelector.TaskTemplate>
    </local:TaskDayTemplateSelector>
```

Under `<UserControl` i'm getting a blue underline and the designer doesn't load.
I added already a constructor to the TaskDayTemplateSelector class but didn't help.
any help please.

Comment: Do you have the correct using for "local" at the beginning of your user control's xaml file ?

Comment: Did you see the InnerException to find out what is causing the nullreference?

Comment: I guess As you are using  <local:TaskDayTemplateSelector.DefaultTemplate>, you are getting this error. That's the reason why your designer is not loading. Do you see any issue when executing app?

Comment: Hi i don't have any issues when executing tha app, the problem is only at design time. and the local refers to my project where the TaskDayTemplateSelector class is defined, and the DefaultTamplate is a property in the class, and the InnerException is None.

Comment: if u have written any logic in constructor of  usercontrol then also might get a problem so please put it in the loaded event of usercontrol